# Is it possible to download emails from Gmail with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, imap

This sounds like a stupid question, but is it possible to download emails from Gmail with jQuery? If so, how?

This is needed as a proof of concept of a larger internal product where we're trying to bypass the server when possible.

Comment: Seems unlikely unless the IMAP server offers an HTTP-API.  To speak IMAP to the server, you would need to be able to open a TCP connection to the IMAP server on a particular port and talk the IMAP protocol.  Even if you tried to use the newish web-sockets, you'd have same-origin issues, port issues and protocol issues.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript IMAP and SMTP client?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775191/javascript-imap-and-smtp-client)

Comment: You could create a WebSocket -> IMAP proxy server. ;)

Comment: Why the down votes? This is a legitimate question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it is not possible to download emails from an IMAP server. What I can think of is to use JQuery to use $.ajax or $.post to connect to a server side function which returns a list of email data to display in the browser. I think that that's as far as you can go, though.

Comment: That's what we assumed, but we just wanted to see if there was a special interface for Gmail.

Comment: I did a little searching and Gmail has an API to retrieve one's inbox (read only mode) in rss format, however it's limited to Google Apps domains (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/#gmail_inbox_feed)

Answer (score 0):

No, because you need at least a server side language.

Why are you asking that special question? Let us know what's behind this jquery-approach-wish.