# Convert ASP.NET SendGrid call into JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, sendgrid

Consider the following ASP.NET example for sending an email using SendGrid. Is there a way to write the equivalent code in JavaScript?

```
    @{
       string message = "";
        if (IsPost) {
            var c = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
            c.Send("from@domain.com", "email@domain.com", "subject", "body");   
        }
    }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, unfortunately javascript doesn't have the sort of TCP/IP access required to create an SMTP / IMAP requests. Also even if it did there would be a whole mess of other concerns, such as the security of a client-side email application that could use your credentials to send spam etc.

The best way to achieve something close to what you're after would be to send an AJAX request to a server that processes the request and fires the email, essentially using the code you have but triggering it from javascript. You can read more about JQuery's AJAX [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) (As this is .net I assume you'd want to use a familiar framework).

This question may be a duplicate of: [Javascript IMAP and SMTP client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775191/javascript-imap-and-smtp-client)

Comment: This answer is true for client side stuff, but definitely false for javascript overall.

Comment: The OP clearly states that they're using ASP.NET / .NET, making this a client-side question. I agree that you could use a different server-side technology such as node.js, but naturally this would require a completely different backend.

Comment: I'm pretty sure ASP.NET is evaluated server side... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET

Comment: It absolutely is! ASP.NET is a server-side technology, but therein lies my point, where javascript fits into an ASP.NET application is purely on the client-side. To implement your suggestion the poster would need to significantly change their backend technology stack / core application language. The context of server-side technology is very important, as javascript is near omnipresent these days!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is definitely possible.  SendGrid has a node.js module that lets you send email from javascript.  You can find it on [github](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs) or on [npm](https://npmjs.org/package/sendgrid).

The equivalent code sample would be:

```
var SendGrid = require('sendgrid')
  , sg = new SendGrid('your_sendgrid_username', 'your_sendgrid_password');

sg.send({
  to: "email@domain.com",
  from: "from@domain.com", 
  subject: "subject", 
  html: "body"
}, function(succ, msg) {
  if(!succ) throw new Error(msg);
});
```